# Bouncing label in Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm building a game where a label should bounce into screen (just once) when the screen is touched (it is inside touchesBegan).

I found [this](https://github.com/ataugeron/SpriteKit-Spring) extension that helped with "bouncing", but I don't know what happens that when I touch restartButton (this button was working just fine) **before** 3 seconds (duration's time?!?!), **myLabel** will just appears without any animation. Am I doing anything wrong?

Ps: restartButton has a removeAllActions(). So even if this animation was on loop (which I guess is not), it would be stopped, wouldn't it?

```
//myLabel
    myLabel.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height)
    myLabel.text = "0"

    self.addChild(myLabel)

    //bounces into screen (using Sprite-Kit Spring)
    self. myLabel.runAction(SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 1.125), duration: 3.0, delay: 0.5, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.2, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0))
```

When restartButton is touched, it calls this function:

```
func restartScene(){
        self.removeAllChildren()
        self.removeAllActions()
        gameStarted = false

        createScene()
    }
```

Ps: `createScene()` is the actual game scene (things such as positions, scales, physics, etc).

Comment: removeAllActions only removes actions that are on the scene, not the actions of its children. RemoveAllChildren does not remove actions. Call remove all actions on your label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working in Sprite Kit, try to take note that SKScene is a member of SKNode.  Calling `removeAllActions` only removes the actions that are applied to the screen, and calling `removeAllChildren` only removes the children, not the actions.

You will need to call `removeAllActions` on all of your children to get them stop moving.

Set up an extension on `SKNode` if you want to have a method for your scene to remove all children's actions.

```
extension SKNode
{
    func removeAllActionsIncludingChildren()
    {
       self.removeAllActions()
       self.children.map { $0.removeAllActionsIncludingChildren()}
    }
}
```